# How to Remove image tag from display

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I am trying to write an onClick function that removes the last added image from the input array from displaying.

Here is my code:

```
<div>
  <form>
    <input type="file" name="pic" accept="image" onChange={this.handleClick} multiple />
    <input type="submit"/>
    <button className={"clear"}>Clear last image</button>
  </form>
</div>
<div style={formStyle}>
  {this.state.array.map((item, i) =>
    <img
      style={imgStyle}
      src={URL.createObjectURL(item)}
      key={i} 
    />
  )}
</div>
```

Here I take a user's input image file and add it to a state array and then I display that array. I can't find a direct post related but is there an optimal way I can remove the last uploaded image tag from the DOM?

Comment: if you remove it from the state it will be removed from the dom as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you could just remove the last item from the array and update the state

```
clearLast = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  this.setState({
    array: this.state.array.slice(0, -1)
  });
}
```

--

```
<button className={"clear"} onClick={this.clearLast}>Clear last image</button>
```

**edit** with changes above

Since the button is inside the form, when you click it's causing the form to submit. If you use `e.preventDefault()` it will stop this behavior.

Also I think you might be able to just add `type="button"` like:

```
 <button type="button" className={"clear"} onClick={this.clearLast}>Clear last image</button>
```

And then the form won't be submitted anyway

Comment: So I believe this function works but it introduces a new problem. When setState gets called it reloads the page and removes all images from the DOM. Is there a way to stop that from happening?

Comment: @Jack updated above -- since the button is inside a form it's causing the form to submit and reload the page. If you use `e.preventDefault()` it should stop that from happening